# java keyPressed method fires too slowly

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I wrote a program to move an image when I press arrow keys(using keylistener). When key was pressed the image move a littele and then wait for about half a second and then moves again smoothly. I want to remove the waiting time. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: Do a quick search on SO, this a common problem which is well documented (hint, use key bindings, a flag and a update loop)